# How to compare and show result in excel?

Tags: excel, ms-office

Ok this will sound complicated but here we go:

So I have one excel which has over 1000+ products with each of them having unique item number. And I have another file which contain discontinued product(with item number). I want to somehow use the item number in discontinued products to delete the products in excel don't match the item number in discontinued product.

Is there a trick to do this in excel or anything program that does? Basically I just want to find all the matched number in both products and discontinued product excel files and delete the unnessary rows. Sorry for bad english. Thanks!

Comment: Use the VLookup function.  It will be able to match the product IDs for you. though it would be easier if the data was in the same workbook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort the dicontinued sheet  by item number. Add a column to the sheet containing the full list. This new column should contain a formula using the MATCH function to test if the product is discontinued.  You can then filter on this new column and delete the rows.

Answer (score 0):

a very simple way is to add a column beside the product item code, 
run a Vlookup to the Products item list which references the discontinued products in this column. 
Then run an autofilter on the top row. 
Limit the vlookup column to all values which are not #N/A
Delete all rows remaining.
your done.